# Asterisk 13 AGI Python: No such file or directory

Tags: python-2.7, asterisk, raspberry-pi3

I installed Asterisk 13 on Raspberry Pi 3 and recently I'm trying to call Python script from Asterisk dialplan. The script contains email sending function and call of that function. I put it in **/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/** and I gave permission to execute with **chmod 777** to whole folder. In dialplan I've got this simply example: **exten => 190,1,AGI(sendemail.py)**. When I try to call this extension I'm receiving error like that:

**Executing [190@default:1] AGI("SIP/1235-00000003", "sendemail.py") in new stack**
**-- Launched AGI Script /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/sendemail.py**
**sendemail.py: Failed to execute '/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/sendemail.py': No such file or directory**
**-- Auto fallthrough, channel 'SIP/1235-00000003' status is 'UNKNOWN'**

What does mean "No such file or directory"?
I just want to execute python script from asterisk dialplan, nothing more. We are not talking about programming asterisk from python. From console level of RPi python script works well.
When I do the same with bash file: **exten => 88,1,AGI(/home/pi/opendoor.sh)** it executes without any error! Opendoor script is changing state of GPIO pin to turn on/off relay for door.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe asterisk don't has read rights and execute rights. Make sure that file exists.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to add a trailing space in the first line of your script:
http://sysout.twoday.net/stories/1022617818/